# Pesquisa no Banco de Dados com valor de <select>

Tags: php, mysql

Como realizo uma pesquisa no banco de dados, através de um parâmetro informado pela tag `select`?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
   <select  class="form-control" id="inputUnidade">
     <option>Selecione</option>
     <option>*GCOI</option>
     <option>ESC - RJ</option>
  </select>
```

Exemplo, caso o usuário escolha "ESC-RJ", pesquisar somente os registros que forem "ESC-RJ". 
Alguma dica?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Adicione na pergunta clicando em [edit] sua tentativa de construção da query, bem como a estrutura da(s) tabelas das quais você quer extrair a informação.

Answer (score 5):

### HTML

```
 <select  class="form-control" id="inputUnidade" name="inputUnidade">
       <option>Selecione</option>
       <option>*GCOI</option>
       <option>ESC - RJ</option>
 </select>
```

### PHP

```
 <?php
      $unidade = $_POST['inputUnidade'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Unidade = '$unidade'";
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema de seu código é que suas `options`, estão incompletas :

```
<select  class="form-control" id="inputUnidade" name="inputUnidade">
    <option value="{valor que sera atribuido ao select}">{alias}</option>
</select>
```

Ela deve possuir o atributo `value` para que o `select` tenha o valor selecionado.

Assim :

```
<select  class="form-control" id="inputUnidade">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="*GCOI">*GCOI</option>
    <option value="ESC - RJ">ESC - RJ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Quando a descrição da option tem o mesmo valor do `value`, ele pode ser omitido sem problema. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option#HTML_Attributes

Comment: @rray desconhecia este fato, obrigado a informação :D

Comment: O primeiro código teu resolveu o problema mas comentou ele, por padrão nenhum valor(tag input/select) é enviado se não tiver o `name`, no código da pergunta só tem `id`;)